# vibrate a floating microbody

Tags: fluid-mechanics, applied-mechanics

I have a tiny plastic disc of dia 1cm submerged inside water in a container in the halfway.
I have to make the disc to oscillate sinusoidal with a frequency(1Hz to 10Hz) and amplitude (1 cm to 5 cm).

I got an [answer](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18357/producing-vibration-motion-of-a-plate-1cmx2cm-placed-in-water) for similar question based on a mechanical method using a loud speaker. But this does not serve the purpose as a vibrating connector creates ripples and affect my observations.

How can I produce such oscillation and control externally without any wires?
I made a failed attempt using Lego gears owing to mechanical instability and interference with other moving parts.
I can use magnetic electric or any other means and I can replace plastic with any other material that can respond to external field variation. Therefore looking for a non mechanical method